# Webix button icons list required

Tags: webix, fontawesome-4.4.0

I am using button icons for my Webix application  as follows :

```
  {view:"button", id:"saveBtn",  type:"icon", icon:"floppy-o", label:"Save", width:100, tooltip: "Save data" }
```

I know other buttons icons to create buttons for serving various purposes. They are 'upload', 'file-text-o', 'download' etc. However I am not able to get the URL which lists down all the available icons which can be used.

Can anybody please point me to that listing URL (probably font-awesome).
This link https://docs.webix.com/desktop__icon.html does not provide the entire list.

Thanks.

Comment: I got it. It is here http://fontawesome.io/icons/ Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [here](http://fontawesome.io/icons/). Remember the version of FontAwesome integrated in your version of webix